Indoor plant identification for re-potting
We were gifted this plant a couple of years ago and I finally got around to re-potting it, however since doing so it's not looked particularly happy...
Plant ID apps tell me it's some type of Dracaena but all the photos I found online have different size or colour leaves.
Any suggestions would be great, as would pointers for repotting medium...



It's Dracaena marginata - not particularly fussy about potting soil, ordinary multi purpose is fine. You don't say what you used to repot, but assuming it was new potting soil, you may have caused a little root damage when repotting, or you didn't water it in well enough. Should have been watered sufficiently well for excess to flow out the bottom of the pot (which should then be tipped away after 30 minutes  so it's not left sitting in water).
UPDATE
It's not a good idea to use anything other than potting soil for container plants - the topsoil and manure you used are not sterile, unlike potting soil, so any pathogens present are now contained in the pot, unable to dissipate like they would in open soil. It might be fine and you get away with it, but it's a risk. I would repot it into proper potting soil asap ...

That's it thank you! I repotted it in a mix of top soil and manure, I think. It's what I had lying around. Should I swap it for a potting compost?

See updated answer

I appreciate your help, thank you.
